# Creating a SelectList which contains Integers

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a dropdown allowing users to select quantity of tickets. I have a createOrder method which displays the tickets available depending on the event chosen. I want to first check how many ticketsAvailable for the event then depending on the quantity available populate my selectlist

Here is my code so far

```
 public ActionResult CreateOrder(int id)
    {
        Event e1 = db.Events.Find(id);
        List<SelectListItem> quantities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ViewBag.listTickets = (from t in db.Tickets where t.EventID == id select t).ToList();
        if (e1.TicketsAvailable == 0)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        else if (e1.TicketsAvailable < 5)
        {
            for (int loop = 0; loop < e1.TicketsAvailable; loop++)
            {
                quantities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = loop.ToString(), Value = loop.ToString() });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int loop = 0; loop <= 5; loop++)
            {
                quantities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = loop.ToString(), Value = loop.ToString() });
            }
        }
            ViewBag.Quantities = quantities;
            return View();

        }
```

And my View

```
<head>
<title>Order</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/TableSheet.css">
@using GeogSocSite.Models
</head>
<body>
<h1>Choose Your Tickets</h1>
<table align="center" cellspacing="2" border="1">
   <tr>
       <th align="center">Description</th>
       <th align="center">Price</th>
       <th align="center">Add</th>
   </tr>
    @foreach(GeogSocSite.Models.Ticket t in ViewBag.listTickets)
   {
   <tr>
       <td align="center">@t.Description</td>
       <td align="center">@t.Price</td>
       <td align="center">@Html.ActionLink("Add to Cart", "AddToCart", "Order", new { id = t.TicketID })</td>
      <td align="center"> @Html.DropDownList("Quantity", new SelectList(ViewBag.Quantities)) </td>
   </tr>
   }
</table>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index","Events")
</div>

</body>
```

However this does not work the text shown in the dropdown is wrong. If I use an ordinary List this works but then I think this means users won't be able to select from these values. If anyone could help me with this I'd really appreciate it as I've been stuck for a long time on this!